how to connect the eureka server and eureka client using different docker-compose files
How can I connect the eureka server and eureka client using docker compose? I have simple client with application.yml where configured the configurations for connection to eureka server:
spring:
  jackson:
    serialization:
      fail-on-empty-beans: false
  application:
    name: usersMicro
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    database: POSTGRESQL
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_test_db
    username: root
    password: admin
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
server:
  port: 8089
#eureka:
#  client:
#    serviceURL:
#      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

eureka:
  client:
    serviceURL:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
    service-url:
      zone1: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
    region: region-1
    availability-zones:
      region-1: zone1

the standard eureka client Dockerfile:
    FROM ubuntu:latest
    LABEL authors="user"
    
    ENTRYPOINT ["top", "-b"]
    
    FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
    VOLUME /tmp
    COPY target/usersMicro-1.jar user-service.jar
    ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/user-service.jar"]

and docker-compose.yml file:
version: "3.9"
services:
  user-service:
    container_name: user-service
    image: user-service
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8089:8089"
    networks:
      - postgres
networks:
  postgres:
    name: shared-network
    external: true

The eureka server is almost the same
the server eureka application.yml is:
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka_server
server:
  port:
    - "8761:8761"

eureka:
  hostname: localhost
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false

eureka server Dockerfile is the same, except lines
    COPY target/eureka_server-1.jar eureka-server.jar
    ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/eureka-server.jar"]

and eureka server docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3.9'
services:
  # EUREKA-SERVER CONTAINER............................................
  eureka_server-service:
    container_name: eureka_server
    image: eureka_server
    restart: on-failure
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    networks:
      - postgres
# NETWORKS CONFIGURATION....................................................
networks:
  postgres:
    name: shared-network
    external: true

My docker-compose files for server and client are in different directories and may be that is the problem, that they should be specified in the same file, but I was able to connect my microservices with DB which is in a strict different drive.
If I start the server and client out of docker, from IDE, I am able to see the connection in eureka web interface, but if docker - in logs, I receive the error that connection refused:
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server or 2024-08-06T13:28:24.835500447Z Caused by: org.apache.hc.client5.http.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to http://localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused
what I miss in these configurations ?

Does Communication between multiple docker-compose projects answer your question?  The important part is that both containers share a Docker network, though it looks like you have that manual configuration already.  As always in Docker, localhost refers to "the current container", so you probably need the Compose service name eureka_server-service as the host name (consider setting the Spring property as an environment variable to not need to modify your source).

Yes, I have configured the network postgres between DB, client, server... etc. And I am able to make sql operations (create tables, make records.....). And I think that that is enough for networking. regarding localhost, do you think that I have to specify the hostname? because I thought that communications between containers  communicating between containers is done via ports and in this case localhost:port is enough to specify the application... or am I confused?

Please see Networking in Compose in the Docker documentation.  localhost always refers to the current container, and it doesn't work to connect to another container.  You very rarely need to specify hostname: in the Compose configuration (RabbitMQ specifically needs it but almost nothing else does).

ok, thanks for pointing.
